# SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm using the `$http.get()` to do a GET request, the response is in JSON, but with HTML encoding for some characters, one example is as below, " is encoded with `&quot;`

```
{
    &quot;description&quot;:&quot;invalid&quot;,
    &quot;errorCode&quot;:&quot;error.loginInvalid&quot;
}
```

Also i'm using         `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpErrorsInterceptor');`, httpErrorsInterceptor will show the error information in `responseError`. Since the response JSON is not decoded properly, when try to process it, it will show `SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON` in console. I wonder how can we decode the response `JSON` when processing? in `$httpProvider`?

Comment: Do you control the source? if so...how does it get that way in the first place? That is not valid json

Comment: @charlietfl yes, it's JSON but some special characters are encoded.

Comment: So why not just remove the extra encoding? (especially that it makes no sense)

Comment: No it's not. JSON rules are very clear about quotes. Those are html entities not quotes wrapping each key/value. If you use a proper serializer it will escape things properly

Comment: And if you need html entities in the values....only encode values...not the whole json string

Comment: @charlietfl i see, but the response is not controlled by me~ There should be no html tags, normally the "

Comment: So is what you are showing the actual response? Or have you encoded it client side. Still not clear how it gets that way or where

Comment: @zerkms these are strings, sometimes not just one word, so remove all is not quite good idea. BTW if remove, u know how to remove?

Comment: @charlietfl the normal response from server is XML, but we have one converter in server to convert XML to JSON, but it's not coded properly, some special characters are not decoded~

Comment: @chancyWu just fix whatever produces it. Working it around is a road to nowhere.

Comment: XML converter defintiely needs to be fixed. Should be very easy to create arrays/objects in whatever server language is used and use that language's json serializer to produce the json. I suspect someone is doing it manually which is always error prone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to convert html entities to text is to create a dom element , inject the string as html and retrieve it back as text. The DOM parser will do better job of converting than writing your own

```
var str='{ &quot;description&quot;:&quot;invalid&quot;, &quot;errorCode&quot;:&quot;error.loginInvalid&quot&quot;}'
var JSON = angular.element('<div>').html(str).text();
```

But example shown is still invalid JSON due to extra quote on last value

[working demo with last `&quot` removed](https://jsfiddle.net/3sr52myL/)

Comment: sorry, i removed the extra quote on last value~

Comment: OK if that's gone this should work...just JSON.parse() the result. Still no good reason the xml converter should be doing this

Comment: I try to find some point to process, but the $http processed as JSON earlier, so when i get the parameter, it throw syntax error already~

Comment: You probably need to treat this as datatype text the way that $http interceptors work. Or write your own XMLhttprequest.This is a really ugly problem that makes no sense really. Someone just being lazy or doesn't understand the JSON spec

Answer (score 0):

The response's content type is `text/html;charset=UTF-8`, but angularjs will parse as JSON since it starts with `{` and ends with `}`, while the content is encoded as HTML, so it would show syntax error when the parser encounters the `&` character.

One solution is to provide the `transformResponse` in the `$http.config`, which is something as below:

```
$http({
  method: 'get',
  url: yourURL,
  transformResponse: transformResponse
});

function transformResponse(data) {
  var json = angular.element('<div>').html(data).text();
  return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

If you want to transform all the response, you may add `transformResponse` to `$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse`.