# Set a Json Serialized Object into session. not able to parse it from the View

Tags: c#, json

Just the Brief Code which is enough to explain my problem i guess.

**Here is my c# code:**

```
List<MaZone> ListZoneValues = new List<MaZone>();

ListZoneValues.Add(new MaZone()
                            {
                                ZoneIc = int.Parse(DataReader["ZoneIC"].ToString()),
                                ZoneName = DataReader["ZoneName"].ToString()
                            });

HttpContext.Session.SetString("ZoneDetails",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListZoneValues));
```

**Here is my javascript code.**

```
var ZoneDetailsVB = '@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ZoneDetails")';

JSON.parse(ZoneDetailsVB);
```

But the error im face is while Parsing the Json.
The Error was:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

**Json string Recieved:**

```
[{"ZoneIc":1,"ZoneName":"Zone1"},{"ZoneIc":2,"ZoneName":"Zone1 & 2"},{"ZoneIc":3,"ZoneName":"Zone2"},{"ZoneIc":4,"ZoneName":"Zone4"},{"ZoneIc":5,"ZoneName":"Zone5"},{"ZoneIc":6,"ZoneName":"Zone 6"},{"ZoneIc":7,"ZoneName":"Zone Num 7"}]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check what is the value of `ZoneDetailsVB`? Is this variable being set correctly, i.e. with valid JSON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194442/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json)

Comment: @RuiJarimba Yes, I am able to recieve the serialized JSON values. But Parsing gives me the error.

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question and paste the json string....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you could do something like this

```
function htmlDecode(value) {
        return $("<textarea/>").html(value).text();
}

var ZoneDetailsVB = '@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ZoneDetails")';    
JSON.parse(htmlDecode(ZoneDetailsVB));
```

You can also use *he* library https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

Third solution is to use

> Html.Raw

```
var ZoneDetailsVB = '@(Html.Raw(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ZoneDetails").ToString()))'
```